# Virtuemart - IF statement after event fired if payment method selected

Tags: php, events, payment, virtuemart

Does anyone know how to add to an event an if statement for true and error?

```
 * @return null if the payment was not selected, true if the data is valid, error message if the data is not vlaid
 *
 */
public function plgVmOnSelectCheckPayment (VirtueMartCart $cart, &$msg) {

    return $this->OnSelectCheck ($cart);

}
```

with this it doesn't work

```
if ($cart != null )  {
    echo "TEST";
}
```

Comment: Your test is failing because of the type hint on your function, `VirtueMartCart $cart`. That basically means to even get into the function, an object of VirtueMartCart has to be passed. A variable that holds an object is not not null. What exactly are you trying to test for?

Comment: i wanted add a html input form if the payment method is selected           
i think i need a other function too plgVmOnSelectPayment() but dont know how to use.